# No default arguments in constructor when using move constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

When I added a move constructor to my child class, I found I can't use default arguments for the constructor.  I've also tried using an overloaded constructor in `base_class` with zero arguments which calls the normal constructor with the arguments passed in manually but I'm having the same issue.

The error message from Visual Studio is: `error C2512: 'child_class<base_class>': no appropriate default constructor available`

```
class base_class {
public:
    base_class(int param1=1) {}
};

template <typename BaseType>
class child_class : public BaseType {
public:
    using BaseType::BaseType;
    child_class(child_class&& move_in)
        : BaseType(std::move(move_in)) {}
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    child_class<base_class> instance1; // MSVC says no default constructor so doesn't compile.
    child_class<base_class> instance2(123); // No problem
}
```

Comment: You probably meant `std::move(move_in)`.

Comment: What makes you think this has to do with the move constructor, rather than the *inheriting* constructor?

Comment: @SebastianRedl Yes, sorry.  copy paste error. I'll fix that.

Comment: @NicolBolas The code compiles fine without the move constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably an MSVC bug in the inherited constructor implementation. Clang compiles the code without complaint.

Comment: This is a bug without any doubt according to the definition of default initialize [\[dcl.init\]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#7)